# Can't open the Angular Module link in next new tab

Tags: angular, laravel, angular-ui-router, angular6

I have an angular page. which is http://schoolerp.dci.in/vidyauraweb/. We have a registration module here http://schoolerp.dci.in/vidyauraweb/registration. But when I try to open this link in new tab this page not found. It's throwing error like this

> notfoundhttpexception
>
> in routecollection.php line 161

We developed this site with laravel + Angular

http://schoolerp.dci.in/ is base URL for laravel

http://schoolerp.dci.in/vidyauraweb/ is base URL for Angular

Comment: Have you created route for that page

Comment: share some code

Comment: What's the problem here? What are you asking? What have you done to try to resolve your problem? What source code caused the problem?

Comment: Yes, this link (http://schoolerp.dci.in/vidyauraweb/registration) is generated by the routing concept.

Answer (score 2):

Angular is a single page application that handles the route on the client side. You will need to add a rewrite rule on your server, to redirect all routes to the index.html page.

What happens is that your server is trying to find the path http://schoolerp.dci.in/vidyauraweb/ which doesn't exist. You need to pass that to the index.html so angular know what component to show instead.

You will need to add a route in laravel to route all requests that are handled by angular to `index.html`

Comment: Do you have any reference to add a route in laravel to route all requests?

Comment: This seems identical [laravel spa](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-you-handle-routes-when-using-spa)

Comment: @VetrivelPandiyarajan if this solves your issue, dont forget to upvote and accept the answer :)  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sure Will do it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to C_Ogoo's answer, there may be times where you don't have much access or control to the server where your app lives.

You could solve this problem entirely on the client side by using the [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy) Your url's would look like this: 
    `http://schoolerp.dci.in/vidyauraweb/#/registration/`

```
// imports of your AppModule
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) 
],
```